# How can i install Mongo Db in Win32 system ?Anyone has installed mongo db in win 32 bit system

Tags: mongodb

Anybody has installed mongo db in win 32 bit system, please help.
I don't find Mongo DB set up file for Win 32 system in mongo db official site.

https://www.mongodb.org/downloads

Here I can see set up for 64 bit but my system is 32. Frown | :(
I just installed RoboMongo without installing any other mongo db setup but I get the following error.

> Unable to connect

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new release is currently for only 64 bits but you can download previous version for 32 bits [link](https://www.mongodb.org/downloads#previous).

PS:- Recommended to use 64 bits.

Answer (score 0):

You could download Mongo DB for 32 Bit Windows OS here --https://www.mongodb.org/dl/win32/i386